# Why do I get typescript errors within nested template literals?

Tags: typescript

For the following code, the first `theme` has no typescript errors, and the second one has `Binding element 'theme' implicitly has an 'any' type.ts(7031)`.

```
export const HeaderNavInner = styled.div`
  padding: ${({ theme }) => theme.spacing.generic[4]}px
    ${({ theme }) => theme.spacing.generic[6]}px;

  ${media.min.medium`
  padding: ${({ theme }) => theme.spacing.generic[4]}px 0;
  `}
`;
```

Is this because it is within nested template literals?

How do I get around this error?

Comment: Please consider modifying the code in this question so as to constitute a [mcve] which, when dropped into a standalone IDE like [The TypeScript Playground (this is a link to a web IDE with your code in it)](//tsplay.dev/w2KQ9N), clearly demonstrates the issue you are facing.  Ideally the only issues present should be the ones you're asking about (no undeclared values). This will allow those who want to help you to immediately get to work solving the problem without first needing to re-create it. And it will make it so that any answer you get is testable against a well-defined use case.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is not with the template literals but with the types of `media.min.medium`.